# guessing random numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a simple function in JavaScript which generate random values in (0,10) and asks the user to guess these numbers. Since I am new with JavaScript I wrote this code which not working. So I need your help to figure out how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your last if statement in `Guessing` checks whether the counter is below 5. Remove that statement and you are good to go. Since `counter` is defined as a global variable, it is increased in the guessGame function even without you giving it as parameter and once it's =5 your code stops executing.

*A tip if you are new to programming in general:* If your code stops working at a magic value,(`5` in this case), it's always a good idea to search it in your code with *ctrl+f*.

Edit after comment:

You are thinking readInput as a blocking function, it's not. Your do...while function executes readInput every time, and reads the same value from the input box and processes it as wrong. To fix it, remove your Guessing function, put readInput in your html, and at the end of your readInput add the guessGame function where you do your comparison with the random numbers. Try with 1 number first.

Fun fact: Even guessing  supposed to work as you intended, it would generate a new set of random numbers at each click, thus make the game much harder.

With 1 number, your code is like this :
html:

```
         Guess : <input type="text" id="nb"/> <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="readInput()"/>
```

javascript:

```
var ranval=generateRandom();
var counter=0;

function readInput(){
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('nb').value);
    if (counter<5){
        guessGame(input);
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter==5){
        console.log("you lost")
    }
}

function generateRandom(){
    //the 3 random values to be used later 
    rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) ;

    ranval=rand1;
}

function guessGame(input){
    if (ranval==input){
        console.log("correct")
    }
}
```